# Convert a <Future> to a Map<DateTime, List<Event>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a future created that returns information from my API.

I need to convert the Future to a different list format, and I'm getting the error

**The argument type 'Future<List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<DateTime, List>'.**

I want to end up with a List like this

```
List<Event> eventList = [
  Event(DateTime(2022, 3, 13), "Meeting", " Meeting in the London"),
  Event(DateTime(2022, 3, 14), "Train", " Train home 13:15pm"),
  Event(DateTime(2022, 3, 13), "Park Run", " 10 am start all welcome"),
  Event(DateTime(2022, 3, 20), "Live Music", " Music by Jimmy Shand"),
  Event(DateTime(2022, 3, 23), "Football Match", " London V Manchester"),
  Event(DateTime(2022, 3, 23), "Darts", " Peter Wright v Phil Taylor"),
];
```

How can I get elements out of my Future<List> to create a list like above.

I know in some languages I could just loop through them and create a new list with the DateTime element first, and other elements then after it and then return the new list.

My new list would look like this after I loop through the Future.

```
List<Event> eventList = [
 
Event(DateTime(map['calendar_dates_start']), map['calendar_event_name'], map['event_images_1'])
Event(DateTime(map['calendar_dates_start']), map['calendar_event_name'], map['event_images_1'])
Event(DateTime(map['calendar_dates_start']), map['calendar_event_name'], map['event_images_1'])

]
```

Here is my Future that doesn't give any errors.

```
Future<List<CalendarDetails>> _getCalendarDetails() async {
  List<CalendarDetails> calenderEventsDisplayed = [];
  try {

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(constants.apicalendarevents));    

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      
      List<CalendarDetails> calenderEventsDisplayed = [];

      for (var map in jsonData) {
        CalendarDetails AllCallendarEvents = CalendarDetails(
          map['calendar_event'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_event_name'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_event_subtitle'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_priority_id'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_dates_start'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_dates_end '] ?? "",
          map['sport'] ?? "",
          map['arts'] ?? "",
          map['music'] ?? "",
          map['notices'] ?? "",
          map['community'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_event_images_1'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_event_images_2'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_events_descriptions'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_website_link'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_contact_details'] ?? "",
          map['calendar_event_live'] ?? "",
        );

        calenderEventsDisplayed.add(AllCallendarEvents);

      }

    }
    
    //return calenderEventsDisplayed;

  } catch (e) {

    print(e);

     } // End try

  throw Exception('Nothing to see');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can "convert" the Future to its underlying type (here it is a List) simply by awaiting the result.

```
final myVar = asynchronousOperation(); // returns Future<Type>
final myVar = await asynchronousOperation(); // returns Type
```

Your method returns a Future .... Whereever you use it you can just await its result.

Regarding the error message it would be nice to see which operation throws the error, because there seems to be a confusion between List and Map too, in addition to the Future topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm going to rewrite the file and check the documentation.